# How to sort a list of Java objects by an attribute contained in another list?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-stream, comparator

Is there any way to sort the list of objects by an attribute that another list contains?

For example I try to sort `ArrayList` `customObjects` of `CustomObject`s by the values of `ArrayList` `models` of `String`s :

```java
ArrayList<CustomObject> customObjects = new ArrayList<>();
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Volvo", 1, "x1", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Bmw", 2, "x2", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Mercedes", 3, "x3", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Alfa", 4, "x4", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Fiat", 5, "x5", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));

ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add("x2");
models.add("x5");
models.add("x1");
models.add("x4");
models.add("x3");
```

Expected result:

```
customObjects = [
  {CustomObject("Bmw", 2, "x2", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4))}
  {CustomObject("Fiat", 5, "x5", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4)}
  {CustomObject("Volvo", 1, "x1", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4)}
  {CustomObject("Alfa", 4, "x4", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4)}
  {CustomObject("Mercedes", 3, "x3", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4)}
]
```

Note that the list sizes could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own comparator for that. I have called your string with X "xString" like this

```
public class CustomObject {

    private final String volvo;
    private final int i;
    private final String xString;
    private final int i1;
    private final int i2;
    private final int i3;
    private final boolean b;
    private final int i4;

    public CustomObject(String volvo, int i, String type, int i1, int i2, int i3, boolean b, int i4) {
        this.volvo = volvo;
        this.i = i;
        this.xString = type;
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
        this.i3 = i3;
        this.b = b;
        this.i4 = i4;
    }

    public String getXString() {
        return xString;
    }

}
```

in your code you can then compare the indexes of the models list like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testSorting() {

        List<CustomObject> customObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Volvo", 1, "x1", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
        customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Bmw", 2, "x2", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
        customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Mercedes", 3, "x3", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
        customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Alfa", 4, "x4", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));
        customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Fiat", 5, "x5", 200, 4, 15000, true, 4));


        List<String> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add("x2");
        models.add("x5");
        models.add("x1");
        models.add("x4");
        models.add("x3");

        // Compator#compare returns int that tells which object is first and which second, see the Javadoc.
        // You can write your own comparator by just subtracting the indexes in the list.
        customObjects.sort((car1, car2) -> models.indexOf(car1.getXString()) - models.indexOf(car2.getXString()));

        System.out.println(customObjects);
    }
```

This doesn't cope with corner cases like the property is not found in the list, null values etc.., but you could get the idea.

Shorter way of sorting but less understandable for people not familiar with lambdas can look like this:

```
    customObjects.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(car -> models.indexOf(car.getXString())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the index of the model.  I shortened your class to make it more visible but the idea is the same.

record for demo puposes

```
record CustomObject(String car, int v1, String getSortId) {
}
```

The data

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> customObjects = new ArrayList<>();
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Volvo", 1, "x1"));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Bmw", 2, "x2"));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Mercedes", 3, "x3"));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Alfa", 4, "x4"));
customObjects.add(new CustomObject("Fiat", 5, "x5"));

ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add("x2");
models.add("x5");
models.add("x1");
models.add("x4");
models.add("x3");
```

The solution.  Using the sortId you are sorting on the relative positions of   that id in the model.

```
customObjects.sort(Comparator
        .comparing(custObj -> models.indexOf(custObj.getSortId())));
customObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
CustomObject[car=Bmw, v1=2, getSortId=x2]
CustomObject[car=Fiat, v1=5, getSortId=x5]
CustomObject[car=Volvo, v1=1, getSortId=x1]
CustomObject[car=Alfa, v1=4, getSortId=x4]
CustomObject[car=Mercedes, v1=3, getSortId=x3]
```

If the sortId does not exist in the model, -1 is returned so that and similar objects will be first in an ascending order sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution utilizing [`Ordering.explicit()`](https://guava.dev/releases/33.1.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(java.util.List)) from the Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library.  This method returns a `Comparator` which orders based on an explicitly ordered list of values.  This code assumes that `getModel` is a getter method for the property to be ordered by.

```java
Comparator<String> modelOrdering = Ordering.explicit(models);
Comparator<CustomObject> comparator =
        Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getModel, modelOrdering);

customObjects.sort(comparator);
```

This code uses [`Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor, keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) to compare `CustomObject` values based on the result of calling `getModel()` on them, using the explicit order comparator compare these `model` attributes.  It uses this `Comparator` with the [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method of `customObjects` values to sort the list.

If any object in `customObjects` has a `getModel` value that is not in the explicit list of values, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown when sorting the list.